# Google Play services Task API: continueWith vs continueWithTask

Tags: android, firebase

This is about [Task](https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/tasks/Task).

What's the difference between `task.continueWith()` and `task.continueWithTask()`, can you provide an example for each one?

Comment: the type of `Continuation` is different

Answer (score 18, accepted):

The primary difference between [continueWith](https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/tasks/Task.html#continueWith(com.google.android.gms.tasks.Continuation%3CTResult,%20TContinuationResult%3E)) and [continueWithTask](https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/tasks/Task.html#continueWithTask(com.google.android.gms.tasks.Continuation%3CTResult,%20com.google.android.gms.tasks.Task%3CTContinuationResult%3E%3E)) is one of the generic types of the [Continuation](https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/tasks/Continuation) you pass to it.

You can think of a Continuation as something that converts some input type to some output type.  If you define a `Continuation<IN, OUT>`, where `IN` is the input type passed to its `then` method via a `Task<IN>`, and `OUT` is the type that method returns.

When calling `continueWith`, you pass a `Continuation<IN, OUT>`, and the `then` method is expected to compute and return the `OUT` value given a `Task<IN>` value as input.  You might choose to do this if you don't have any blocking work to do for the conversion, such as reducing an integer array to the sum of its elements or counting the number of words in a String.

When calling `continueWithTask`, you pass a `Continuation<IN, Task<OUT>>`, and the `then` method is expected to return a `Task<OUT>` that eventually generates the `OUT` value, given the `IN` value as input.  You might choose this if you are able to delegate the conversion work to an existing reusable Task.

Practically speaking, you aren't required to choose one or the other to do your work.  It's a matter of preferred style, or if you have a nice `Task` ready to delegate your conversation rather than a `Continuation`.  Typically you only use a Continuations if you have a pipeline of conversions to chain together.

The javadoc links here show some examples of Continuations.  Also, to learn more, you can read about them in [part three](https://firebase.googleblog.com/2016/09/become-a-firebase-taskmaster-part-3_29.html) of my blog series.  To be fair, `continueWithTask` is the only part of the Task API I don't directly discuss anywhere in that series, mostly because conceptually it doesn't differ very much from `continueWith`.

Comment: This is slightly out of date as currently there's another difference between continueWith() and continueWithTask() related to task cancellation.

More info here - [Task API docs](https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/tasks/Task).

Comment: The tutorial on your blog is amazing, THANK YOU!

Answer (score 6):

Just to add to what Doug said, I would put it like this:

`continueWith` will wrap the result of the `then` method in a `Task`.   `continueWithTask` will not; it expects the `then` method to return a `Task`, and thus avoids the double wrapping of a task within a task.

`continueWithTask` is perfect when you want to use a Continuation and a TaskCompletionSource together.

Answer (score 3):

I'd like to add, that `continueWith` and `continueWithTask` really got me into trouble, obviously because I did not truly understand the API, but also did the naming confuse me. Maybe an example of my failure can prevent others from doing the same.

### tl;dr

When to use which method:

1. Use `continueWith` if you want to use the result of the previous task and return a new result within your Continuation's `then` method. And you need to hand it over to some other continuation or use it afterwards in listeners. **The return value of continueWith is a Task that just WRAPS your return value of the `then` method.**
2. Use `continueWithTask` if you want to use the result of the previous task, 
   and somewhat use it in a **new task**, that you create within your Continuation's `then` method. **The return value of continueWithTask is a task that YOU create inside of `then` and has an own generic result.**

---

Do *NOT* return a task in your continuation's then and use it with continueWith. It might compile and execute for years without a warning, but also without doing it's job.

> IF you directly append a listener after `continueWith`, this listener
>   will give you a task THAT ONLY WRAPS the result of your `then` return
>   value. If this return value is a task itself, do not expect it to be
>   executed(!!!).

---

**Long story!**

I had a calling chain like this:

```
private Task<SomeResult> getTask() {

    PreloadingTask.create().continueWith(additionalTask()).addOnCompleteListener(task -> {
        if (task.isSuccessful()) {
            source.setResult(someResult);
        } else {
            source.setException(new Exception());
        }
    });
    return source.getTask();
}
```

So as you can see, `additionalTask()` must return some sort of `Continuation<IN, OUT>`, that implements the method then as

```
@Override 
public OUT then(Task<IN> task){ ... }};
```

In my case I did not need to check for `OUT`, because I just wanted to do some additional computations AFTER the `PreloadingTask` was done and forwards it's result to my `additionalTask()` continuation.

I wanted to execute the task from `additionalTask()`, and afterwards the `onCompleteListener` should have been called.

```
private Continuation<PreviousResult, Task<Void>> additionalTask() {
        return task -> {
            PreviousResult r = task.getResult();
            simpleResultModification(r);
            return new AdditionalTask(r);
            );
        };
    }
```

What happend? The `onCompleteListener` was called directly, because my `then` method got executed and returned it's result, which was an instance of `AdditionalTask`.
This `AdditionalTask` then got wrapped **into another task** and handed over for the onCompleteListener as the result.

> And my **AdditionalTask** got never executed.

**That's why you should use continueWithTask if you return a task, within then.**

Answer (score 0):

There's a big difference between `continueWith()` and `continueWithTask()` related to task cancellation.

More info here - [Task API docs](https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/tasks/Task).

- `continueWith()` : If the previous Task is canceled, the returned Task **will also be canceled** and the Continuation would not execute.
- `continueWithTask()` : If the previous Task is canceled, the Continuation **would still execute** and task.isCanceled() is true can be observed in the Continuation.