# How to create custom tasks for Firebase using the Google Play services Task API

Tags: android, firebase

I'd like to create custom [tasks](https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/tasks/Task) like these ones in [firebase](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/android/com/google/firebase/auth/FirebaseAuth.html#signInAnonymously()) in order to chain my API async calls. How can I achieve that?

Comment: Full example at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37215071

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There are a few ways to create a custom task using the Play services Task API.

First, there is [Tasks.call(Callable)](https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/tasks/Tasks.html#call(java.util.concurrent.Callable%3CTResult%3E)).  The Callable you pass is scheduled for immediate execution on the main thread, and you get a Task in return, with a generic parameter of the return type of the Callable.  This Task resolves successfully with that return value, or an error if the Callable throws an exception.

The other method is [Tasks.call(Executor, Callable)](https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/tasks/Tasks.html#call(java.util.concurrent.Executor,%20java.util.concurrent.Callable%3CTResult%3E)), which is exactly like the other method, except the given callable is scheduled for immediate execution on a thread managed by the given [Executor](https://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/concurrent/Executor.html).  It's up to you to find or create an Executor that's appropriate for your work.

Lastly, there is also [TaskCompletionSource](https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/tasks/TaskCompletionSource), which lets you create a Task and manually resolve it to success or failure from the result of some other item of work not directly related to a Task.

For more details, check out my blog series on Tasks.  I cover these methods in [part three](https://firebase.googleblog.com/2016/09/become-a-firebase-taskmaster-part-3_29.html) and [part four](https://firebase.googleblog.com/2016/10/become-a-firebase-taskmaster-part-4.html).

Comment: Thanks. I'm gonna test that later. Would you mind to talk about  Tasks.forException() and Tasks.forResult()? Small examples would be nice too.

Comment: Those just create Tasks that are already resolved to the given result or exception.  You probably will never use those, but are handy for testing when you need a Task with a known value.

Comment: BTW, nice blog about these tasks! Now I'm getting the point! You really should add other parts talking about the rest of the Task api. I'm in love with this. It fits so much well. I think I'm going to rewrite my api (I'm using retrofit) to support tasks. I hate when I have to chain calls one within the other, and RxJava IMO is so much complicated and ungly. Tasks are beautiful lol. Maybe that might be a good blog post for you too, how to chain retrofit calls using tasks. Just a suggestion ;)

Comment: Although the part3 is practically that. :D

Comment: Actually, I forgot to mention here that you can create Tasks from other sources of work (such as RxJava observables) using TaskCompletionSource.  That's in part 4 of the blog.

Answer (score 5):

Suppose you have a `Document` class, you could do as follow:

#### Create successfuly [resolved task](https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/tasks/Tasks.html#forResult(TResult))

```
Tasks.<Document>forResult(document);
```

#### Create a [failed task](https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/tasks/Tasks.html#forException(java.lang.Exception))

```
Tasks.forException(new RuntimeException("Cool message"));
```

#### Create from [Callable](https://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/concurrent/Callable.html)

```
interface CreateDocument extends Callable<Document> {
    @Override
    Document call();
}
Tasks.call(new CreateDocument());
```

#### Create using [task completion source](https://www.google.com.br/webhp?sourceid=chrome-instant&ion=1&espv=2&ie=UTF-8#safe=off&q=android%20taskcompletionsource)

```
Task<Document> createDocument() {
    TaskCompletionSource<Document> tcs = new TaskCompletionSource();
    if (this.someThingGoesWrong()) {
        tcs.setException(new RuntimeException("Cooler message"));
    } else {
        tcs.setResult(Document.factory());
    }

    tcs.getTask();
}
```